# how to define rails 3.1 custom routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to route `http://localhost:3000/users/1/rename/alex` to my `users` controller with `rename` action.

what I did was:

`match 'users/:id/rename/:name' => 'users#rename'`, but this is not working, the  part after `'users/:id/'` is not mapped at all, since I cannot get name by `params[:name]`

Update:
In routes.rb

```
resources :users do
  put 'rename/:code', :action => :rename, :code => /\w{5}/, :on => :member
end
```

and,

```
$ rake routes
...
PUT /users/:id/rename/:code(.:format) {:code=>/\w{5}/, :action=>"rename", :controller=>"users"}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `resources :users`, put your `match` line before it.

Alternatively, you can pass a block to `resources`:

```
resources :users do
  match 'rename/:name' => 'users#rename', :on => :member
end
```

Comment: but please use a `POST` / `PUT` request!

Comment: Good point @MarianTheisen. I'll leave it as "match" for now since I don't know exactly what his "rename" action is (could require a GET request), and leave it up to him to change it accordingly.

Comment: I guess, I need this: `put 'rename/:name' => 'users#rename', :on => :member` since the rename is really an update action on user model.

Comment: Yeah, if the action will be doing any saving or destroying of any type, it shouldn't be accessible via GET. The difference between PUT and POST is something I still don't fully understand... I stick to: If it's creating a record, use POST, updating use PUT, destroying use DELETE.

Comment: I tried to put `match 'users/:id/rename/:name' => 'users#rename'` before `resources users`, also, put your code into the block, change the match to `put`, none of them works

Comment: Edit your question with the relevant output of `rake routes` please, as well as the relevant parts of your `routes.rb` file.

Comment: Okay, what happens when you go to that route?

Comment: when I browse to localhost:3000/users/1/rename/abcde, there occurs a routing errors: `No route matches '[GET] "/users/1/rename/abcde"`, if I change the `put` to `get`, then I am only routed to `users/1`

Comment: You have "confirm" in your routes, not "rename"... ?